# Import Slides doesn't working on Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

So, I'm trying to Import Ionic Slides to my project, but I'm getting this message: *"... has no exported member 'Slides'"*

I'm importing like this:

```
import { Slides } from '@ionic/angular';
```

then the rest of the code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild("audio") audio;
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let self = this;

    this.audio.nativeElement.oncanplaythrough = () => {

      this.audio.nativeElement.onplay = function () {

        self.slides.autoplay = 1000;
        self.slides.startAutoplay();

      };

      this.audio.nativeElement.onpause = function () {

        self.slides.autoplay = undefined;
        self.slides.stopAutoplay();

      };

    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This answer on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16737#issuecomment-447267665) says there is a rename in the documentation for Ionic 4. Renaming `Slides` to `IonSlides` should do the trick.

> Please take a look at the breaking changes for beta.18: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#angular-prefixed-ion--components
>
> Everything is prefixed with Ion, so instead of Slides it's IonSlides:
>
> ```
> import {IonSlides} from '@ionic/angular';
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> @ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: IonSlides;
> ```

Comment: I've tried, but then I'm getting other error : 'autoplay' does not exist on  type 'IonSlides'.

Comment: Did this solve the import issue you were asking about?  --  As for the next question, you can ask a new question about the `autoplay` property change, but it's likely enough that the IonSlides documentation will answer this for you. Here is the link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

Comment: Yes, It did; I'll ask a new question about autoplay. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {IonSlides} from '@ionic/angular';

export class HomePage {
@ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: IonSlides;
```

Answer (score 1):

this one solved my problem in ionic 4

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
export class IntroScreenPage implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('slides', { read: true, static: false }) ionSlides: IonSlides;
```

i passed second parameter  { read: true, static: false }